# Multiple extruded polygons Mapbox iOS

Tags: swift, mapbox, mapbox-gl

**Latest Mapbox SDK and Swift**

So I've been battling with this for 3 days now...

I'm trying to use an array of coordinates to create a line of extruded cylindrical pillars (or a sloped solid "wall" if that makes sense... But I've found this to be harder than just a line of pillars)

I've read most of Mapbox's docs but can't get my head wrapped around the use of MGLShapeSource, MGLPolygon and MGLFillExtrusionStyleLayer.

From what I can tell, one needs to add a polygon to a source, add that source to the map object, then apply the extrusion layer to that source... However, I can't figure out how to make that work.

[image: This is what I've managed so far, as a solid wall... But using pillars, I could adjust the height as the line goes, creating a sloping look]
`This is what I've managed so far, as a solid wall... But using pillars, I could adjust the height as the line goes, creating a sloping look`

Any advice would be appreciated. I'd paste my code here but it is WAY too messy and too much after 3 days of trial and error. haha.

BONUS: I'd like to animate the path being created as it goes... So pillar 1 appears at a certain height, then pillar two and a lower height, then pillar 3 and so on. This involves modifying the source apparently - have little idea on how to do that though :(

Comment: @Shekhu link to Swift code: https://pastebin.com/mC0MVmQM

Comment: The file is 10mb so too big.. But it follows the standard GeoJSON format which you can find online :)

Comment: dropbox link or something like will help as the GeoJSON files that I have tried didn't draw as expected, shown in the image

Comment: do check my question, the link is above in your question  as stuck in same concern that you have solved

Answer (score 1):

Are there individual `height` properties associated with the points in your underlying data? Your end goal is definitely possible, but it's dependent on whether or not you have the data for reference by your style layer.

Unfortunately, the Mapbox site doesn't have any iOS examples explicitly tied to this. But, the [3D buildings example](https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/maps/examples/extrusions/) follows basically the same flow. (i.e. `mapView.addSource -> MGLFillExtrusionStyleLayer -> layer.fillExtrusionHeight`).

The crucial bit in the building example is using `.fillExtrusionHeight` with a ["forKeyPath" expression](https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/api/maps/4.9.0/predicates-and-expressions.html) to set the extrusion height based on the corresponding property in your data:

```
layer.fillExtrusionHeight = NSExpression(forKeyPath: "height")
```

If you *don't* have height within your underlying data, you'll have to get some in order for the extrusion styling to work this way.

---

⚠️ Disclaimer: I currently work for Mapbox ⚠️

Comment: have a look https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57524439/how-3d-map-visualizations-on-ios-using-mapbox